# Get FPS of video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

How do I get the FPS of a video using AVFoundation in an iOS app? I have tried the code below, but it does not seem right.

```
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [myAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
NSLog(@"FPS is  : %f ",videoAssetTrack.nominalFrameRate);
```

Comment: what is your issue? what desire result you want?

Comment: I want FPS of video.

Comment: try to get individual frames of the video - then do image processing to find which one differs. the difference b/w the duration of two image framed will most probably be the fps

Comment: I got solution. Thanks for help

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, it might help other people.

Comment: Posted solution

Answer (score 5):

I got correct FPS with below line of code :

```
AVAsset * myAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL: _videoUrl options: nil];
AVAssetTrack * videoAssetTrack = [myAsset tracksWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
NSLog(@"FPS is  : %f ", videoAssetTrack.nominalFrameRate);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### AVAsset extension for Swift 5

```
extension AVAsset {
   /**
    * Get FPS from AVAsset
    */
   var fps: Float? {
      self.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first?.nominalFrameRate
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 16**

You can benefit from Swift concurrency development to retrieve `FPS`, `size or dimension`, and `duration`, by using [Load](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets/loading_media_data_asynchronously) properties asynchronously.

```
var asset: AVAsset? = AVAsset(url: filePath)
if let asset = asset,
   let videoTrack = try? await asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .video).first {

     let size = try? await videoTrack.load(.naturalSize)
     let fps = try? await videoTrack.load(.nominalFrameRate)
     let duration = try? await asset.load(.duration)
}
```